# Add custom domain to be used with firebase real time database (i.e. verify email links)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I am looking for an option to change domain name that is being used for real time database features like email verification / password reset. At the moment emails that are sent to users use default `project-name.firebaseapp.com` domain names. It would be good to use custom domains for this. I believe firebase hosting allows to achieve this, yet there is nothing about domain change for real time database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email verification and password reset are part of the Firebase Authentication, so are documented/configured there.

For example: [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#link_to_your_custom_handler_in_your_email_templates) mentions the firebaseapp.com domain problem at the bottom (in the blue box).

The email templates (and sender address) can be configured in [the Authentication tab of the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/emails).